# Using angular includes like mvc partials

Tags: angularjs

Consider the following:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplateName">
{{item.SomeProperty}}
<script>

<div ng-repeat="container in List">
    <div ng-repeat="item in container.Items">
        <!-- CASE 1 -->
        <div ng-include="'myTemplateName'"></div>
    </div>    
    <!-- CASE 2 -->
    <div ng-include="'myTemplateName'" />
</div>
```

The code above works in case1, but not in case2: case 1 will work because the template uses **item**, which is made available by the ng-repeat statement outside of the template, case 2 doesn't work because there is no **item**, instead i want it to use container.SomeProperty.

Maybe i am misusing angular includes, but i wanted to use them like partials in ASP.Net MVC. There, you can define a partial and you are able to pass in a model.

Is there any way in angular that allows me to set what **item** means inside the template?

**Problem solved using Matt's answer:**

```
module.controller("ItemController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.templateitem = ($scope.$parent.item) ? $scope.$parent.item : $scope.$parent.$parent.container.Item;
}]);
```

Still, it feels kind of dirty: the controller needs to know how it can be used. It would be better if i could pass this to the controller from the outside.

**A better approach:**

I didnt really like the solution above, because the controller needs to know how it will be used, so i used a directive:

```
app.directive("opportunity", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "opportunityTemplate",
        scope: { templateitem: "=model" }
    };
});
```

In view:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="opportunityTemplate">
    {{templateitem.SomeProperty}}
</script>

<opportunity model="container.Item"></opportunity>
<opportunity model="somethingElse.Item"></opportunity>
```

Now all i need to find out is how i can pass the templatename into the directive, and i can make a re-usable "partial" directive (please tell me if i am reinventing the wheel here?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to use is `ng-controller`, or some routing system like `ui-router` that connects partials to controllers through route definitions.

For the first example, when you add your partial, also specify a controller which takes care of dealing with the model:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-include="'myTemplateName'" />
<!-- inside the template -->
<div>{{item.somekey}}</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myapp.ctrl', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.item = { somekey: 'somevalue' };
    }]);
```

In the second example, use a routing system like ui-router. An example of that can be seen here, where certain partials are attached to controllers and specific urls:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/gh-pages/sample